# How can I troubleshoot why Unity Dash Search doesn't always find applications?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Sometimes the improper search result is shown as follows:

[image: Unity 1]

I need to <kbd>Escape</kbd> the search and re-do it do get the proper result:

[image: Unity 2]

Comment: Do you have zietgiest daemon starting at login?

Comment: It's not part of my `Startup Application Preferences`. Can you show me how the entry looks on your system as a reference?

Comment: Sorry I can't. I'm currently in distance with my system. but if it is there, problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! As said, it's not there on my system.